# Consistency checking with 2 arrays issue

Tags: php, arrays

When consistency checking between 2 arrays, what is needed so that the position immediately following an anomaly is not skipped. Could someone post a loop that iterates over 2 arrays and prints whether or not values match?

```
$arr1 = array('apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'orange', 'melon', 'kiwi');
$arr2 = array('apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'melon', 'kiwi');
$count = 0; //keeps track of position to be checked in arrays.
```

The loop should print true, true, true, false, true, true in this case. It should be noted that when an anomaly is found, that value is removed so future values are checked with the position normalized to account for the removed erroneous value. I have tried using unset() followed by array_values() but the next value is always skipped. It's an off-by-one nightmare for me. Any ideas?

```
$count = 0;
$lines = file("url");
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){
    if(strcmp(sub($line, 0, 3), 'gis') == 0){
        $site = sub($line, 3, 7); //get latitude eg. gis4021
        if($site != $sites[$count]){
            //deal with case where $site does not equal expected value in base array
        }
        else//$sites equals expected value in array
            $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual goal here? Is it to find the values that exist in both arrays, and if so, would [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) work better for you?

Comment: You should also post the code you're using that isn't working.  You don't need to modify either array in order to accomplish what you're describing.

Comment: Is `$arr2` always the "reference" array? i.e. The array with the desired values?

Comment: will edit shortly with actual code

Answer (score 1):

This works but obviously you'd need to add some kind of error checking, e.g. to see if `$arr2` is not longer than `$arr1`:

```
$arr1 = array('apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'orange', 'melon', 'kiwi');
$arr2 = array('apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'melon', 'kiwi');

$count = count($arr1);
for ($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if ($arr1[$i] == $arr2[$j]) {
        $j++;
        print 'true ';
        continue;
    }

    print 'false ';
}
```

The code outputs `true true true false true true`.

As you can see it iterates through ALL entries of `$arr1` as `$i` always gets incremented, however, `$j`, which is the iterator for `$arr2` only gets incremented if a matching value is found.